# How to enable AWS ElasticSearch domain's Error logs using Terraform

Tags: terraform-provider-aws, aws-elasticsearch

I'm wondering if Error Logs could be enabled from Terraform scripts for `ElasticSearch` domain, which can be configured from `AWS Console`.

But as per Terraform documentation the [supported log_types for ES domain](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/elasticsearch_domain#log_type) are: `INDEX_SLOW_LOGS, SEARCH_SLOW_LOGS, ES_APPLICATION_LOGS`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Error Logs" you are referring to are the ones `ES_APPLICATION_LOGS` gets you => specify a `log_type = "ES_APPLICATION_LOGS"`

See e.g. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/es/describe-elasticsearch-domain.html which states

> ES_APPLICATION_LOGS: Elasticsearch application logs contain information about errors and warnings raised during the operation of the service and can be useful for troubleshooting.

Comment: Thanks @luk2302 , I have overlooked at the documentation.